WiX v4 Toolset: schedule reading a value from Windows Registry
Is it possible to schedule reading a value from the Windows Registry?
I have a CustomAction that needs to be executed before a registry value is read and saved to a Property. I'm trying to kind of 'wrap' RegistrySearch within a Custom Action. Not sure this is even achievable.
Could you please help me with the approach?
<Property Id="PropId">
    <RegistrySearch Id="RegId"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\..."
                    Name="Install"
                    Type="raw" />
</Property>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- MyCustomAction is supposed to be executed before the reg reading action (RegId). -->
    <Custom Action="MyCustomAction" Before="???" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>


RegistrySearch is executed by the AppSearch action. So you can schedule your custom action before/after AppSearch.
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- MyCustomAction is supposed to be executed before the reg reading action (RegId). -->
    <Custom Action="MyCustomAction" Before="AppSearch" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>


Rob, thank you very much for reply! I've tried this configuration and there is this exception: Error 2732:  Directory Manager not initialized. I guess the problem is that my script uses the .bat file from the target dir. Is there any way to handle this case? Thank you in advance!
